# WordPress 5.6 Application Passwords

Tags: php, rest-api

I have reviewed [this page](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/11/05/application-passwords-integration-guide/) but could not fully understand it. Does this feature in 5.6 provide us with an interface?

[image]

The page displayed above did not appear in my admin panel. Also I write url manually myself and it said "Application passwords cannot be used." I got this warning.

Is there a way to open this on the "wp-config.php" side?

Also thanks.

Comment: "By default, Application Passwords is available to all users on sites served over SSL/HTTPS." Do you have an SSL certificate?

Comment: If it doesn't open because it doesn't have an SSL certificate (Localhost), it means it's not showing up because I'm working on it.

I will try this. In that case! Thank you.

Comment: @JacobPeattie So why didn't the menu appear in the panel? So if only the menu was accessible and it said unavailable because it does not have an SSL certificate:?:

Comment: Suppose I am working with SSL certificate (HTTPS). So, will a menu be added to the Admin panel? Do you have information? Or is it necessary to use only a URL to access the relevant page?

Comment: It wouldn't be in the menu because it's useless unless you're directed there with a  proper URL. This is all described in the article you linked under "Authorization Flow". You should see the stuff on the Edit User screen though, if you have an SSL.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Thank you for all the comment. If you add a summary of these comments as an answer I can mark it as an answer.